# Pandas randomly swap columns values per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to train a binary classification ML model with some data that I have; something like this:

```
df 

y   ch1_g1  ch2_g1  ch3_g1  ch1_g2  ch2_g2  ch3_g2
0   20      89      62      23      3       74
1   51      64      19      2       83      0
0   14      58      2       71      31      48
1   32      28      2       30      92      91
1   51      36      51      66      15      14
...
```

My target (`y`) depends on three characteristics from two groups, however I have an imbalance in my data, a count of values of my `y` target reveals that I have more zeros than ones in a ratio of about 2.68. I correct this by looping each row and randomly swapping values from group 1 to group 2 and viceversa, like this:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():

choice = np.random.choice([0,1])

if row['y'] != choice:

    df.loc[index, 'y'] = choice

    for column in df.columns[1:]:

        key = column.replace('g1', 'g2') if 'g1' in column else column.replace('g2', 'g1')

        df.loc[index, column] = row[key]
```

Doing this reduce the ratio to no more than 1.3, so I was wondering if there is a more direct aproach using pandas methods.
¿Anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Plz forgive my ignorance, but what does swapping columns have anything to do with class unbalance?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not swapping columns solves class unbalance aside, I would swap the whole data set, and randomly choose between the original and the swapped:

```
# Step 1: swap the columns
df1 = pd.concat((df.filter(regex='[^(_g1)]$'),
                 df.filter(regex='_g1$')),
                axis=1)

# Step 2: rename the columns
df1.columns = df.columns

# random choice
np.random.seed(1)
is_original = np.random.choice([True,False], size=len(df))

# concat to make new dataset
pd.concat((df[is_original],df1[~is_original]))
```

Output:

```
   y  ch1_g1  ch2_g1  ch3_g1  ch1_g2  ch2_g2  ch3_g2
2  0      14      58       2      71      31      48
3  1      32      28       2      30      92      91
0  0      23       3      74      20      89      62
1  1       2      83       0      51      64      19
4  1      66      15      14      51      36      51
```

Notice that row with indexes `1,4` have `g1` swap with `g2`.